# finding the Thursday immediately before the 3rd Friday of each month in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to find the Thursday before the 3rd Friday of quarterly month (mar / jun / sep / dec)

Last 3rd Friday is given by:

```
dates = (
        pd.date_range(start="1981-03-01", end="2029-09-30", freq=pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(3, week=1, weekday=3))

)
```

Appreciate the help !

Comment: So you're looking for the third Thursday in the month

Comment: `weekday=3` looks like you're already looking for a Thursday

Answer (score 0):

```
#rough code    
import datetime
    thursdays=[]
    for y in range(2021,2022):
        for m in range(1,12+1):
            for d in range (12,19) : # later find out  the exact range
                my_date=datetime.date(y,m,d)
                if my_date.weekday()==3:
                    thursdays.append(my_date)
    for th in thursdays:
        print(th.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```